# Removing duplicates in ArrayList w/o Hashset

Tags: java, arraylist

I am able to remove most of the duplicates except for the ones that are right next to each other. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Right now I have nested for loops comparing an int to the rest in the ArrayList. except how I either setup or increment I am skipping the duplicate next to where I start the first for loop over again. I have found it useful to reset my i=0 after I remove my index j. It still won't remove the duplicate if they are right next to each other.

```
for(int i=0;i<original.size();i++){
    for(int j=i+1;j<original.size();j++){
        if(original.get(i)==original.get(j)){
            original.remove(j);   
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I found my solution, when I changed my second for loop to a while loop, then incremented each time, but when I found a duplicate I removed 1 from j. That way I would be starting over.

Thank you all.

Comment: I'm curious why you don't want to use a `HashSet`, since that is a more efficient method.

Comment: I like to know how to do it without the knowing 'easy' way helps me with problem solving.

Comment: @user1241388 how does asking on stackoverflow "help you with problem solving"?  If you want me to write the answer for you I will, but..

Comment: b/c I have made it this far, but sometimes you have to ask for help. and to clarify the indices are of Double type.

Comment: Only increment j if you don't remove the element.

Comment: @brettw. True, (I gave your comment a +1) but even simpler is to have j loop backwards.

Comment: @user949300 Please post your solution as an answer and accept it. That will be useful in the future.

Comment: @trojansdestroy added code to my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You should use iterator to remove element in the list, rather than using the List itself.

Answer (score 1):

Notes:

1) where you **remove** from an Arraylist , the size will be **decreased** and the index will be **decreased** !!!

**Ex:**

if the original arraylist is: {a,b,c,d} , and the index i = 2 (c) ; 
if you remove the original(2) ( ===== remove c from the original ) the index will be i++ refereing to original(3) wich it Does not exist !!!!

2) And what is the type of your objects ??? if they are a Strings so you will use the **.equal()**

Comment: I think that your problem is where you remove an element from the original , the index (i) changed !!!!

Comment: if the original arraylist is: {a,b,c,d} , and the index i = 2 (c) ; if you remove the original(2) ( ===== remove c from the original ) the index will be i++ refereing to original(3) wich it Does not exist !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals` instead of `==`. Change if statement like:

```
 original.get(i).equals(original.get(j))
```

Comment: That is good because it will check value not reference, but if I have an ArraList of (7,7,7,7) it will still return (7,7) not (7)

Answer (score 0):

Use the obj.equals(obj other) function to compare strings or objects, not the == operator.

```
  for(int i=0;i<original.size();i++){
  for(int j=i+1;j<original.size();j++){
      if(original.get(i).equals(original.get(j))){
          original.remove(j);
      }
  }
  }
```

If you want to remove object based on some value of that object then you need to override equals method of your bean class.
Please have a look over at equals method in java.
If u override bean class no need of two for loop to remove duplicates. You can avoid duplicates while adding object to an array list.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you wouldn't want to use a `HashSet`, regardless you need to use `.equals()` instead of `==`, since you're looking at the value, not the reference.  Additionally, if you're using loops and you remove an element from the list, you don't want to increment `j` as this will skip an element, which obviously you don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are looping by index over a List and removing, *you must loop "backwards"*.  Have j loop backwards.  Otherwise you end up skipping over entries.  As @BinaryMan also noted.

e.g. (note, also using equals() instead of ==)

```
for(int i=original.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
    for(int j=original.size()-1;j>i;j--){
        if(original.get(i).equals(original.get(j))){
            original.remove(j);   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume the list looks like this : `[a,a,a,b,c,a]`

This is how the iterations will look like (view is after the iteration is done, delete or no delete):

```
i=0, size = 6 , j=1, arr[i] = a, arr[j] = a, view: [a,a,b,c,a]; (arr[i]==arr[j], will delete)
i=0, size = 5,  j=2, arr[i] = a, arr[j] = b, view: [a,a,b,c,a]; (arr[i]!=arr[j])
i=0, size = 5,  j=3, arr[i] = a, arr[j] = c, view: [a,a,b,c,a]; (arr[i]!=arr[j])
i=0, size = 5,  j=4, arr[i] = a, arr[j] = a, view: [a,a,b,c];   (arr[i]==arr[j], will delete)
i=1, size = 4,  j=2, arr[i] = a, arr[j] = b, view: [a,a,b,c];   (arr[i]!=arr[j])
i=1, size = 4,  j=3, arr[i] = a, arr[j] = c, view: [a,a,b,c];   (arr[i]!=arr[j])
i=2, size = 4,  j=3, arr[i] = b, arr[j] = c, view: [a,a,b,c];   (arr[i]!=arr[j])
i=3, size = 4, .......
```

The neighbors will not delete because j=i+1, it will never get the chance to check against eachother because once you remove an element the array is shifted down by one index so at the next iteration the item you were going to check is actually skipped because of `j=i+1`

Comment: The same thing will happen if the sequence is somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

If array elements are ints it would be more efficient to sort the array first

```
    Collections.sort(list);
    Iterator<Integer> i = list.iterator();
    int prev = i.next();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        int next = i.next();
        if (next == prev) {
            i.remove();
        } else {
            prev = next;
        }
    }
```

Note that `original.get(i)==original.get(j)` for Integers does not compare values, that is `new Integer(1000) == new Integer(1000)` produces `false`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class RemDupFromList {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List li = new ArrayList();

              li.add("one");
              li.add("two");
              li.add("three");
              li.add("one");//Duplicate
              li.add("one");//Duplicate

             // We have facility to pass a List into Set constructor and vice verse to cast      

                List li2 = new ArrayList(new HashSet(li)); //no order

             // List li2 = new ArrayList(new LinkedHashSet(li)); //If you need to preserve the order use 'LinkedHashSet'

             Iterator it= li2.iterator();
             while(it.hasNext())
             {
                 System.out.println(it.next());
             }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> wordDulicate = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> tempList= new ArrayList<String>();

    wordDulicate.add("7");
    wordDulicate.add("7");
    wordDulicate.add("7");

    for (String dupWord : wordDulicate)
    {
      if (!tempList.contains(dupWord)) 
      {
        System.out.println(dupWord);
        tempList.add(dupWord);
      }
    }
```

In `templist` you will get no duplicate entry.